# Angular 17 ERR NG9: Property 'roomsCatalog' does not exist on type 'RoomsCatalogComponent

Tags: javascript, angular

Good day!
I am developing a practice UI code in Angular 17 but getting error upon `ng serve` for the entire project:

`NG9: Property 'roomsCatalog' does not exist on type 'RoomsCatalogComponent'.`

Project code can be found here [GitHub repo link](https://github.com/Linux-Maniac/angular_learning) and path for the mentioned file is `my-workspace\projects\new-hotel-inventory\src\app\rooms\rooms-catalog\rooms-catalog.component.ts`

> The **rooms-catalog.component.ts** file is:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RoomDetails } from '../rooms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-rooms-catalog',
  templateUrl: './rooms-catalog.component.html',
  styleUrl: './rooms-catalog.component.scss'
})
export class RoomsCatalogComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() roomsCatalog: RoomDetails[]=[];
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

> The **rooms.ts** file imported into **rooms-catalog.component.ts** file is:

```
export interface RoomCount{
    totalRooms : number;
    availableRooms : number;
    bookedRooms : number;
}

export interface RoomDetails {
    roomType : string;
    roomNumbers : number;
    amenities : string;
    price : number;
    photos : string;
    checkinTime : Date;
    checkoutTime : Date
}
```

> Also the **rooms-catalog.component.html** file is:

```
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Index</th>
      <th>Even/Odd</th>
      <th>Room Type</th>
      <th>Number of rooms</th>
      <th>Room Amenities</th>
      <th>Checkin Time</th>
      <th>Checkout Time</th>
      <th>Room Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let room of roomsCatalog; let e = even; let o = odd; let i=index;"
        [ngClass]="e? 'odd' : 'even'">
        <th>{{i+1}}</th>
        <th>{{e? "Odd" : "Even"}}</th>
        <th>{{room.roomType}}</th>
        <th>{{room.roomNumbers}}</th>
        <th>{{room.amenities}}</th>
        <th>{{room.checkinTime | date}}</th>
        <th>{{room.checkoutTime | date}}</th>
        <th>{{room.price}}</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Would appreciate any help in this regard!

Many thanks in advance

Tried checking the error online but got no help. Confused as `roomsCatalog` is present as a property in the exported class `RoomsCatalogComponent`

> Please find the screenshot of the execution process:

[image]

Comment: Your component doesn't have any properties https://github.com/Linux-Maniac/angular_learning/blob/main/my-workspace/projects/new-hotel-inventory/src/app/rooms/rooms-catalog/rooms-catalog.component.ts#L9

Comment: Hi @yurzui thanks for responding. Somehow the properties got missed while uploading the project. I have updated the component file. Could you kindly check again where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Should I run `ng serve newHotelInventory`? After running this I only see `core.mjs:11760 ERROR Error: NG0500: During hydration Angular expected <tr> but found <tbody>.` in browser. Which can be fixed by wrapping `trs` into `tbody`

Comment: Hi @yurzui I am running `ng serve` from location **my-workspace\projects\new-hotel-inventory** . I have edited my question with the screenshot of the execution process with the errors for reference.

Comment: It works for me. Try to clone your repo from scratch, then run `npm i` and `ng serve`

Comment: Hi @yurzui your suggestion worked like a charm for me. Many thanks for your help!